# How to tell Xcode to flush CoreData output to Sqlite

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, core-data, ios-simulator

I'm working with CoreData in Xcode 10. The backing data store for CoreData is Sqlite. I'm working on a Swift application which is to be deployed to iOS; dunno if that's relevant.

Is there a way to tell Xcode (or Simulator, I guess), after running the application, to flush any output to the Sqlite file on disk? Sqlite output seems to be flushed only when Xcode and/or Simulator is closed, which is a little clumsy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A managed object context should be explicitly saved, soon after its data has been changed.  This is something you should be doing in your code, not a feature of Xcode or Simulator.  Implement and call a function which saves the relevant managed object context.  Do not wait until your app terminates.

```
func save() {
    do {
        try self.managedObjectContext.save()
    }
    catch {
        let nserror = error as NSError
        NSLog("Whoops! \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

However, if you are using parent and child contexts, things are a little more complicated.  [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext?language=objc) explains this nicely:

*When you save changes in a context, the changes are only committed “one store up.” If you save a child context, changes are pushed to its parent. Changes are not saved to the persistent store until the root context is saved. (A root managed object context is one whose parent context is nil.) In addition, a parent does not pull changes from children before it saves. You must save a child context if you want ultimately to commit the changes.*

For a SQLite store, the *persistent store* they refer to is the SQLite files on the disk.  (By default, there are three SQLite files on disk: the main file, the -shm file and the -wal file).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There are indeed calls to context.save in the code, however, that doesn't appear to cause data to get flushed from CoreData to Sqlite. That seems OK to me; it's up to CoreData to decide when to flush its own data store to disk. But perhaps I have misunderstood how CoreData works.

Comment: Ah, possibly you are using parent and child managed object contexts.  See the last two paragraphs I just added to my answer.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I'm saving a child context, and the parent context is saved upon some application-level events (entering the background, termination, resign active). I misunderstood what was going on before, but now that you have described it, I understand more clearly. Essentially what I am hoping to find is some action I can take within Xcode to have the equivalent of parent.save(). But now that I think about it, it's not really any big deal to swipe up on the simulator to trigger the save, so maybe I'll just plan to do that. Thanks for your help.